# Truffle vs Meteor

Tags: truffle, meteor

I have developed a dApp using Meteor. My question might sound a little dumb but here it goes: What is the difference between Truffle and Meteor? Are they exclusive from each other, is either one or the other? I know I can develop a dApp using Meteor because I have already done that but everyone is talkung about Truffle and I don't really get what is it and what can I use it for.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor and Truffle are two different frameworks. As you already experienced Meteor is a javascript framework to design single page web applications.

Truffle can be used to devlop and test smart contracts which are written in Solidity. In order to test the smart contracts it is recommended to use testrpc. Testrpc simulates a blockchain wich runs on your local computer. If you use Truffle and testrpc you don't have to deploy your contracts to the  ethereum blockchain which can safe you money and time.

If you want your meteor app to interact with your smart contracts you would need to install ethereum-web3 https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Dapp-using-Meteor

I hope this helps